# iOS: UITableView lagging with image data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, nsdata

I have a UITableview that has a list of images like so. But it is very laggy for some reason when I scroll up and down. Any way to stop this? The images dont need to be reloaded. It needs to stay static.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}
ContentModel *contentModel = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:contentModel.txtImages];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
cell.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may better use AFNetworking UIImageView Methods:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://image.com/image.png"]];
```

Even with a PlaceHolder:

```
[self.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://image.com/image.png"] placeholderImage:     [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"]];
```

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

This will dramatically reduce the lag on your tableview.

Answer (score 0):

We have very similar requirements but my code works perfectly, I am guessing that 
 these commands slow down your routine:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:contentModel.txtImages];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
cell.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

instead I use the following:

```
    NSString *icon = CurrentQRCode.parsed_icon;
  NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:icon ofType:@"png"]; 
    UIImage *image_file = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    cell.imageView.image = image_file;
```

the whole routine is below:

```
QRTypeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[QRTypeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}


    CurrentQRCode = (QRCode *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *icon = CurrentQRCode.parsed_icon;
    NSString *string = CurrentQRCode.parsed_string;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:icon ofType:@"png"]; 
    UIImage *image_file = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    cell.imageView.image = image_file;
    cell.labelview.text = string;
```

I believe I originally tried handling UIImages using initWithData but found them a lot slower than the other methods.

Comment: Paulo you are loading your resources locally vs. the poster loading via URL. Big difference.

Comment: Mine are local, if you need to access the images from the network - maybe you should try what @user3290977 is suggesting and see if it will be better, otherwise I would suggest you download all the icons in a tmp file the same time you are creating your datasource

Comment: What would be the reasoning for downloading all the icons at once? That is assuming the poster knows all the images. I don't think downloading all the images in one go is the right way to go. But maybe you have a reason for it?

Comment: You  do not want the screen display / or the startup to be dependent on something that may not be consistently available . Network connection is fickle for most mobile users, go up a lift and its gone.  The fact that your datasource is an array leads me to suspect that your data is not absolutely real time and I assumed that this is something you can do to improve the usability of your app.

Comment: I just realised you are not the poster - What's with your comments?  There is not enough information to figure out what kind of data the app is using, the commands used can refer to both local and network data.     The fact that the rest of the datasource is an array probably means that the data is not absolutely real time. in which case t will be better to do it once than multiple times every time the tableview is loaded / reloaded.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by NSArray and realtime. Simply pointing out downloading all your images at once is probably not the correct solution for what the poster is trying to accomplish. I tend to disagree that there is not enough info to see what he is trying to accomplish, or at least offer that downloading all images is maybe not the way he wants to go.

Comment: There is no point in discussing this with you, the poster needs to clarify what he is doing,  the URL string in self.tableArray can refer to network or local objects.  Assuming that you are correct - that it came from the network - his self.tableArray must come from the network as well, it will behave better to download what he needs to create the tableview once than stop and go while creating the UITableViewCell which is what causes the jerky behaviour. Another thing is the URL to data to UIIimage is extremely slow vs. PNG, or JPG to UIImage.

Comment: One other thing, I read your answer regarding GCD and creating a subthread for network activities, subthreading works if there is loose dependency between the task you subthread and the main thread, like if you download while the app is doing some other task.  In the case tableviews, particularly with tableView
cellForRowAtIndexPath  the main thread will keep waiting for your subthread to finish to paint the cell think about it!

Comment: Not trying to argue with you, but you may want to do some reading on moving network request to another thread. I don't think you quite understand what GCD is.

Comment: I am not arguing about the benefits of putting async task like network request on another thread, the main thread  is also used by iOS aside from the active app. I have a music app and I use threading since IOS5. But this is a tableview method. there maybe some benefits in doing the url to data to UIimage in a subthread, but if the main cause of wait is the network, subthreading will not solve anything, you cannot paint the next row until you get the icon for the current row and it will remain jerky.  I'm not a GCD guru but I've never seen subthreading done in cases like this.

Comment: I recommend you look into it. Firing off a separate thread request for an image part of a table view cell is very common practice.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever ever ever load data from a network on the main thread. Use GCD or a framework like AFNetworking or restkit. The worst thing you could ever do to you app is lock up your main thread with things that can be computed off the main thread. A good rule of thumb is to ask is this something that is updating the UI, if not think about moving it to another thread.

I would also look at some of the WWDC videos about multithreading and anything related to moving off the main thread if you really want to understand the reasons why.

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

[RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestK)

[GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html)